# how to call data from laravel mailable in a view

Tags: laravel, return, laravel-blade, laravel-mail

I have a mailable class that sends an email to someone that makes a contract. Now I'm trying to style the mail but... I can't quite seem to call the variable that I pass in the mailable class return.

I've tried passing it to the view in the mailable class and I've tried calling it but in the mail it doesn't show up.

this is my mailable class:

```
public function build()
    {
        $data = array(
            'comapny' => $this->data['company'],
            'file' => $this->data['file'],
            'subject' => $this->data['subject'],
            'email' => $this->data['email']
        );
        foreach($data['email'] as $mail)
        return $this->view('mails.contract')->with('data' , $data['company'])->to($mail)->subject($data['subject'])->attach($data['file'])->withSwiftMeassage(function ($message){
            $swiftMessage = $message->getSwiftMessage();
            $headers = $swiftMessage->getHeaders();
            $headers->addTextHeader('From', 'example - contract <example-email@gmail.com>');
            $headers->addTextHeader('Reply-To', 'example-email@gmail.com');
            $headers->addTextHeader('X-Mailer:', 'PHP/' . phpversion());
        });
    }
}
```

the view i need to call the data to:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p><?php echo $data ?></p>
</body>
</html>
```

any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `with()` with arrays.

Replace `->with('data' , $data['company'])` with `->with(['data' =>  $data['company']])`

Comment: i did this but it still doesn't show up in my mail am i calling it right or should it be something like `echo $this->data`

Answer (score 0):

If you are returning a view to render data for the mail template (in this case i suppose its mails.contract template), do you have a blade template that is located in resources/mails/ and named contract.blade.php?

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/mail#configuring-the-view

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/mail#view-data

Comment: yes i get the view in the mail just without the variable

Comment: take a look at this line, where you define data variable: 'comapny' => $this->data['company'],

Comment: i saw that, i fixed it but it doesn't do anything i still don't get the data unfortunatly

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a variable into the mailable class like.

Need to create a constructor and define a public function.

```
public $data;

public function __construct( $parameter )
{

    $data = /*Your logic define here and assign to `$this->data`*/
    $this->data = $data;

}

public function build()
{
    return $this->view('mails.contract')->with(['data' => $this->data])
        ->to($mail)->subject($this->data['subject'])
        ->attach($this->data['file'])
        ->withSwiftMeassage(function ($message){
            $swiftMessage = $message->getSwiftMessage();
            $headers = $swiftMessage->getHeaders();
            $headers->addTextHeader('From', 'example - contract <example-email@gmail.com>');
            $headers->addTextHeader('Reply-To', 'example-email@gmail.com');
            $headers->addTextHeader('X-Mailer:', 'PHP/' . phpversion());
        });
}
```

> any public property defined on your mailable class will automatically be made available to the view.